# How do I display Category titles on a WP Page?

Tags: php, categories

I am trying to get a list of my Wordpress categories to display on a Page, but haven't cracked this yet.

So far, I have been able to create a **custom category page** (category-categoryname.php), to display a list of Page Titles associated with a single category. The code I have used for this includes the following Loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
```

However, I am now trying to display a list of Category titles on a normal WP Page, using the plugin "Post Snippets" to insert the PHP.

**Q1:** How do I change The Loop to display all Category titles, instead of Pages associated with a single category?

**Q2:** Is there anything else I need to add, like some code to functions.php etc?

**Q3:** Would it be easier to create a custom page template, instead of pasting into a regular page?

Note, I am not trying to filter out any categories from the list, like sub-categories or categories without associated pages/posts etc. Although filtering out 'Uncategorised' would be nice.

Thank you for reading

Comment: How do you want to display the category titles? Just a simple list?

Comment: Note: I wrote my question on the assumption that a different type of Loop would be entered into the Snippet, but please do enlighten me if this is not necessary.

Also, in case it is relevant, I am using the 'Genesis framework', with a customised 'Sample' theme.

Comment: Answer: Yes, just a simple list for the time being. I might develop it into something more fancy in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want [`wp_list_categories ()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories). With a short set of arguments you should be able to get the results you want, including excluding "uncategorized". Something like:

```
$args = array(
  'exclude' => 1,
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to structure the code in the link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/ into the correct use on a snippet or custom page? ... I have just tried this: <?php /* Template Name: Show all categories */ ?> 

<?php wp_list_categories ( string|array $args = '' )
'show_option_all' (string) 
'orderby' (string) default is 'ID'

'order' (string) default is 'ASC'
'show_count' (bool|int) default is 0
?>

<?php genesis(); ?> ... but it has just given me a PHP fail warning on the page - line 5, which starts with: <?php wp_list_categories

Comment: I'm not in ring of a computer. Give me an hour or so

Comment: No probs. Am v. grateful for your help

Comment: @Toby: See the edit

Comment: Many thanks. This works - the snippet displays the categories in a list. I will now try to find the correct Genesis WP commands to display the rest of the page properly.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Loop only works with *posts*. Categories (as in *terms* of category *taxonomy*) aren't posts and don't have concept of archive in WP.

You can build a list easily via [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) and other related functions. For performance reason a page with page template would probably work better for it (so you are not querying number of posts just to throw them away).

Comment: Thanks, I am using the plugin "Add Categories to Pages" to enable the assigning of Pages under Categories, just like Posts. 
I would like to be able to add a snippet of PHP in there.

I have also tried creating a custom page template. However, it just displays the categories on the top left of the entire page. I would like to be able to place it where I want, but the 3rd PHP command at the bottom seems to generate the entire WP page, so I assume I'll need to get "into" it some how:

    <?php /* Template Name: All categories */ ?>
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
    <?php genesis(); ?>

Comment: Between third party plugin and Genesis there I have no guess what is going on in your template there, sorry. :)